# How can I know a named pipe have data to read in java on linux

Tags: java, linux

I create a name pipe, and I want to communicate a python process and a java process. Java process is a game process. When update function is called, I want to check the whether the named pipe has any data to read. But if I called FileInputStream.read(), the process will block. Is there any unblock way to check weather the pipe can read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the [`available()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available--).  If it returns a nonzero value, you can read that many bytes without blocking.  If it returns zero, no input is availble.

Alternatively, instead of repeatedly checking whether input is available, you might be interested in the NIO [`Selector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html) class, which can wait for input with a timeout.  (But you'll need to change your program to use an NIO channel instead of an `InputStream`.)

Answer (score 0):

**Easy way:**

Start a separate `Thread`, let that `Thread` block on the `FileInputStream` and signal when it has read (perhaps by putting the data is has read in a `Queue` or `BlockingQueue`.

**More complex way:**

(but more flexible, especially if you have multiple input sources that you don't want to block on_

Use `java.nio.channels.FileChannel` to open the named pipe, and use `java.io.channels.Selector` to poll for input data becoming available.